# How to save a game in LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm working with LWJGL for the first time, and Im enjoying it. I'm having a slight problem finding tutorials about things like making main menu, or saving/loading game state/information. Are there any decent tutorials available for this kind of thing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depending on what you're doing. A good idea for saving and loading is to use an XML file for each save. You could store any map data, or character data inside that file, then read all of that information when loading.

There are actually some pretty good tutorial series on YouTube:

TheCodingUniverse - http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL19F2453814E0E315 (33 Videos so far)

There are also a lot more random tutorials on youtube if you just search for LWJGL tutorials.

Also if you plan on making 2D games, I would check out [Slick2D](http://www.slick2d.org/). It's basically a 2D engine built off of LWJGL, it can be very helpful in rendering graphics, and stuff of that nature. Keep in mind it's only for 2D though, if you want something like that for 3D, I would check out [JMonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.com/)

The forum [Java-Gaming](http://www.java-gaming.org/) can also be a useful place, these are some of the resources I used when first learning stuff with LWJGL. In my opinion I think going with a library like Slick or JMonkey is the way to do things, because they've done the stuff that is needed for every game, and leave you to make your game.

Comment: Also other great resources are reading the wiki's and documentation for the libraries. Like the LWJGL wiki and documentation, or even the Java documentation can be helpful. Anytime you learn a new language, or library, the documentation for it can be your best friend. In the case of LWJGL, a lot of what you need to know is OpenGL, so reading stuff from http://www.opengl.org would be very helpful. A lot of OpenGL stuff will be in C++, but it's very easily adaptable, just a simple syntax change. All of the functions or methods are basically the same.